# Retrieving values from nested map in golang

Tags: go

I'm trying to retrieving a value from a map within a map. I have followed online tutorials but not getting the right answer. This is my program:

```
type OptionMap map[string]interface{}
func(options OptionMap) {
    opt, _ := options["data2"].(OptionMap)
    fmt.Println("opt", opt)
    for key, value := range options {
        fmt.Println("Key:", key, "Value:", value)
    }
}
```

options has two keys data1 and data2 . Inside for loop the printf prints following

```
Key: data1 Value: false
Key: data2 Value: map[h:5]
```

When I run the code

```
opt, _ := options["data2"].(OptionMap)
```

I'm getting `nil` in `opt`. I'm not sure how to retrieve value of `map[h:5]`.

Comment: Please show us the code how you construct the nested map.

Comment: I'm not constructing it. This map is constructed by docker. BTW im getting the right value map[h:5] but I'm not sure how to retrieve the value of inner map.

Comment: Please get in the habit of using [`gofmt`](https://golang.org/cmd/gofmt/). It will make your code easier for you, and others to read.

Comment: When I print options =>  map[data1:false data2:map[h:5]]

Comment: Please include the _complete_ code, including where you build your nested map. I can't really tell what you're trying to do.  What does `map[h:5]` mean?

Comment: This is what I got when i print options["data2"].  h-key 5-value

Comment: If you want meaningful results when printing a map, be sure to use `fmt.Printf("%#v", map)` or `fmt.Printf("%+v", map)`.  Or consider using a package like [spew](https://godoc.org/github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew) for even more informational data dumps.

Comment: ok i found it. Instead of this `opt, _ := options["data2"].(OptionMap)` I have replaced this  `opt, _ := options["data2"].(map[string]interface{})` it worked..im not sure whats the issue with previous one though

Answer (score 1):

You are getting nil value for inner map because you have not created inner map using type OptionMap.You must have created it using map[string]interface{} and trying to assert to OptionMap which is failing in getting nil value. See below example which is working with OptionMap type,too.Go through type assertion page at https://tour.golang.org/methods/15

```
package main

import "fmt"



type OptionMap map[string]interface{}

func main()  {
    opt := make(OptionMap)
    ineeropt := make(OptionMap)     // while creating Map specify OptionMap type
    ineeropt["h"]=5
    opt["data1"] = false
    opt["data2"] = ineeropt
    test(opt)


}
func test(options OptionMap) {
    opt, _ := options["data2"].(OptionMap)  //If inner map is created using OptionMap then opt won't be nil
    fmt.Println("opt", opt)
    fmt.Println("opt", options)
    for key, value := range options {
        fmt.Println("Key:", key, "Value:", value)
    }
}
```